# firebase cloud function not sending email correctly javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I've created a cloud function which returns the status 200 (ok) when invoked but the email is not received at the destination and I'm not sure if it has actually been sent correctly. In the firebase console it has been invoked correctly. Where am I going wrong here? Please help!

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const key = require('./*************.json')
const my_email_address = 'info@exampledomain.com'
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp();



/**
 * The below function is for sending the invite email.
 */

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
auth: {
    type:'OAuth2',
    user: my_email_address,
    serviceClient: key.client_id,
    privateKey: key.private_key
}
});

exports.sendMail = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
cors(req, res, () => {
  
    // getting dest email by query string
    const dest = req.query.dest;

    const mailOptions = {
        from: my_email_address,
        to: dest,
        subject: 'Invite',
        html: `<p style="font-family:arial;font-size:16px;">Welcome,</p>
            <br />
            <p style="font-family:arial;font-size:16px;">You have been invited to join! Please follow the link to register.</p>
        ` // email content in HTML
    };

    // returning result
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (erro, info) => {
        if(erro){
            return res.send(erro.toString());
        }
        return res.send('Sent');
    });
});    
});
```

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.